# How to select multiple columns after applying group by a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group by "sender" column and extract some related columns.Here is part of my dataset:

```
row number,type,rcvTime,sender,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z,hed_x,hed_y,hed_z
0,2,25207.0,15,136.07,1118.46,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
1,2,25208.0,15,136.19,1117.14,0.0,0.22,-2.31,0.0,0.14,-1.48,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
2,3,25208.81,21,152.66,904.56,0.0,0.06,-0.75,0.0,0.18,-2.43,0.0,0.07,-1.0,0.0
3,2,25209.0,15,136.69,1113.79,0.0,0.39,-4.18,0.0,0.15,-1.64,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
4,3,25209.81,21,152.98,902.59,0.0,0.22,-2.91,0.0,0.12,-1.68,0.0,0.07,-1.0,0.0
5,2,25210.0,15,133.77,1108.01,0.0,0.58,-6.17,0.0,0.16,-1.76,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
6,3,25210.81,21,153.25,898.68,0.0,0.37,-4.65,0.0,0.11,-1.35,0.0,0.08,-1.0,0.0
7,2,25211.0,15,134.37,1100.75,0.0,0.76,-8.14,0.0,0.18,-1.93,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0
8,3,25211.81,21,153.82,893.0,0.0,0.65,-6.67,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0
9,3,25211.93,27,122.87,892.12,0.0,5.63,0.32,0.0,-1.57,-0.09,0.0,1.0,0.04,0.0
```

Here is what I have tried and the result is just all the 'rcvTime' data for that sender However I need all other columns like pos_x,spd_x as well:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/h/trace.csv")
df.head()
df1 = df.groupby('sender')['rcvTime'].apply(list).reset_index(name='new')
print(df1)
```

What I need is the following data, I just wrote for sender=15:

```
rowNumber,sender,rcvTime,pos_x,spd_x,rcvTime,pos_x,spd_x,rcvTime,pos_x,spd_x,...
0,15,25207.0,136.07,0.0,25208.0,136.19,0.22, 25209.0,... 25210.0,..., 25211.0, ...
1,21,25208.81,152.66,0.06, 25209.81,..., 25210.81,..., 25211.81,..., 25212...
2,27,25211.93..., 25212.93..., 25213.93..., 25214.93..., 25215...
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you search for something like this:

```
df1 = df.groupby('sender',as_index=False).agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

**EDIT**

I'm sure there is a better way, but here how I managed to achieve your desired output:

```
cols = ['rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x']
grouped = df.groupby('sender')[cols]
list_of_lists = [tup[1].values.flatten().tolist() for tup in grouped.pipe(list)]
res = pd.DataFrame({'sender': grouped.groups.keys(), f'{cols*len(grouped.groups.keys())}' : list_of_lists})
print(res)

   sender ['rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x', 'rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x', 'rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x']
0      15  [25207.0, 136.07, 0.0, 25208.0, 136.19, 0.22, ...                                     
1      21  [25208.81, 152.66, 0.06, 25209.81, 152.98, 0.2...                                     
2      27                           [25211.93, 122.87, 5.63]
```

Still think, you don't benefit of the possibilities with pandas when formatting your data like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I need to extract values of some columns for each sender for example I need something like, df1 = df.groupby('sender')['rcvTime','pos_x','spd_x'].apply(list).reset_index(name='new')

Comment: please add a table with your desired output. It's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: Thanks, now is that clear?

Comment: I'm sure that's possible but may I ask why you want it in that format? What is the bigger goal of you here ? Can't see any benefit doing it like the way you want it at the moment

Comment: I want to use a code that uses time series data for each sender to find anomaly. The code needs the data to be time series, for each id, I need its data to be time series

Comment: edited my answer. Have a look. To your problem: You don't mention time series at all in your question and no matter what you need to find/compare/filter by, it doesn't help if you have huge lists of values in a single column per row.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually your code didn't give me the correct answer

Comment: hm ok. Did you test to run my code with your example data in your question ? because based on that you get the right result.

Comment: Yes here is what I get:                            
   sender  \
0      15   
1      21   
2      27   

  ['rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x', 'rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x', 'rcvTime', 'pos_x', 'spd_x']  
0  [0.0, 2.0, 25207.0, 15.0, 136.07, 1118.46, 0.0...                                       
1  [2.0, 3.0, 25208.81, 21.0, 152.66, 904.56, 0.0...                                       
2  [9.0, 3.0, 25211.93, 27.0, 122.87, 892.12, 0.0...